# Unbalance page cache in favour of write activities

Tags: linux, storage

I'm using a SMR (Shingled magnetic recording) disk. This technology is known to perform poorly on non-sequential write operations.

It is quite fast at sequential write operations:

```
fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=temp.file --rw=write --size=2g --io_size=10g --blocksize=1024k --ioengine^Cibaio --fsync=10000 --iodepth=32 --direct=1 --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting
...
WRITE: bw=121MiB/s (127MB/s), 121MiB/s-121MiB/s (127MB/s-127MB/s), io=7276MiB (7629MB), run=60217-60217msec
```

It is slow at non-sequential write operations:

```
fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=temp.file --rw=randwrite --size=2g --io_size=10g --blocksize=4k --ioengine=libaio --fsync=1 --iodepth=1 --direct=1 --numjobs=32 --runtime=60 --group_reporting
...
WRITE: bw=510KiB/s (522kB/s), 510KiB/s-510KiB/s (522kB/s-522kB/s), io=30.1MiB (31.6MB), run=60427-60427msec
```

The ratio is 237.

I'm using:

```
echo 30 > /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure
echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio
echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio
echo 360000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
echo 360000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs
mount -o noatime,nodiratime
```

In heavy `rsync` activity I observed:

1. through `collectl` that reading is qualitatively good and writing is poor;
2. dirty field of `/proc/meminfo` doesn't exceed 3G with the buff/cache of about 12G.

I'd like to unbalance the pagecache in favor of write operations and prevent that reading operations flush written pages from cache. I hope to see an improvement in `rsync` execution by cache grouping of writing sequences.

Is there any way to do a such imbalance? I know it is not good tuning but just for test.